# ¿Que valor toma el if() de esta seccion de JavaScript, true o false?

Tags: javascript

Soy nuevo en JS y quiero saber que valor tomo el if (drawer.style.left) , al principio vale -30% (lo cual creo que es falso) por lo tanto va al else, y luego cuando vuelvo a apretar entra al if, pero no entiendo porque si ahora vale -10% y creo que es falso.

Muchas gracias.

```js
  let menu = document.querySelector(".material-icons");
  let drawer = document.querySelector("#drawer");
  menu.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   if(drawer.style.left){
    drawer.style.left = '';
    drawer.style.transition = 'all 0.8s';


   }
   else
   {
    drawer.style.left = '-10%';
    drawer.style.transition = 'all 0.8s';
   }

  });
```

Comment: Como estas agregando el estilo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La propiedad `.style` en javascript solo funciona con estilos que han sido declarados en linea.  Ademas, las propiedades en css son de tipo string, por lo que cualquier propiedad que no este vacia va a retornar true.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {     
    let menu = document.querySelector(".material-icons");
  let drawer = document.querySelector("#drawer");
  menu.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      console.log(drawer.style.left);
   if(drawer.style.left){
    drawer.style.left = '';
    drawer.style.transition = 'all 0.8s';
        console.log(true);
   }
   else
   {
    drawer.style.left = '-10%';
    drawer.style.transition = 'all 0.8s';
        console.log(false);
   }

  });
});
```

```html
<div id="drawer" style="left: -30%">Test</div>
<button class="material-icons">Icons</button>
```

Comment: Si esta fuera la causa del error del usuario y quisiera tratar con el valor del estilo independientemente de si ha sido declarado en línea o no, puede hacer uso de la función window.getComputedStyle (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)